# Why SETTING the color after REVERTING a FILTER losses accuracy?

Tags: html, css, filter, colors

I am trying to create a dark-mode like scenario for a simple HTML page.

I have a class say `child` under class `parent` defined in `light.css` as:

```
.parent{
}

.child{
  background: #780000;
}
```

In `dark.css`, I invert the entire (to create dark mode) html as:

```
html{
  filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

.parent{
  filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

**I want to keep some elements to their original colors.** So, I again `invert` and `hue-change` on those elements. But, that doesn't help because reversing the filter can cause losses. Next, I bet on setting the color of such elements explicitly to be #780000 in `dark.css`. But, still no help.

**My question is after all these invert+revert+hue-changes, how can I make the color of the .child to be exact #780000?**

And

**Why does the color of `child` not change (or sets to pure #780000) even after setting the color explicitly in `dark.css` as:**

```
html{
  filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

.parent{
  filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

.child {
  background: #780000;
}
```

How to fix this?

A MWE (non javascript-based) is as follows:

```css
html{
  filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}

.parent{
  filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
  background: green;
}

.child {
  background: #780000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  I'm parent.
  <div class="child" style="background: #780000">
    I'm child.
  </div>
<div>
```

TOP is what I expect (also the one with no filters).

BOTTOM is what I get (after `Filter+Revert_Filter` or `Filter+Revert_Filter+Explicit_Coloring`).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi there! Great question. Just one more thing. Can you please create a fiddle out of it? Easier for everyone to inspect and play around.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow your question...  *"I know that reversing the filter can cause losses."* -> So you probably understand that's why you can't fall on the same exact color. *"Why does the color of child not change"* Because you apply two `invert(100%)`on it, which *kind of* cancel themselves, and two `hue-rotate(180deg)` which *kind-of* make an `hue-rotate(360deg)`, i.e *kind-of* `hue-rotate(0)`.

Comment: @Kaiido: tx for the edit and explanation. I totally get that. My question is after all these `invert+revert+hue-changes`, how can I make the color of the `.child` to be exact #780000?

Comment: Well you can't really, at least not in any scalable way. You could try to find what specific color would end up on #780000 with the loss induced by the filters, but I doubt you can find a formula which would work for any color. The easiest is to refactor your code so that you don't have to counter the filters, i.e just disable the filters on these elements, which probably means applying more granular filters on other areas.

Comment: No sure, filter do apply to the whole stack, like opacity. You can not filter any parent of `.child`. So for instance .child a sibling .filter-me, you would have to apply the filter only on .filter-me.